# Vue Material md-table md-table-cell

Tags: vue.js, vue-material

I want change the padding style of the child div md-table-cell with classname .md-table-cell-container

I attemp:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
 .md-table-cell-container {
    padding: 0px !important;
  }
</style>
```

but no successful. Can someone help me?

Comment: You're never targeting `md-table-cell`.

Comment: this tag not exists

Answer (score 1):

I've find the solve:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
...
</style>

<style lang="css">
  .md-table-cell-container {
    padding: 0px !important;
  }
  .md-table-head-label {
    padding-left: 0px !important;
  }
</style>
```